# An exercise in Treves related to Cauchy-Riemann operator

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

This is part of the exercise 5.10 from the book "basic linear partial differential equations" by  Treves:

" Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial in one variable, with complex coefficients. Describe all solutions in $\mathbb{R^2}$ of the partial differential equation 
  $P(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}})h=0$. "

I tried a lot of methods end up being messed up. For example, it is natural to write $h=u+iv$ and $P(z)=R(z)+iT(z)$, where u,v are real valued functions and R, T are polynomials with real coefficients. Therefore we have 
$R(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}})u-T(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}})v=0$
, and $T(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}})u+R(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}})v=0$. But unfortunately, I got stuck here.  I also tried using change of variables, but I found it was impossible to derive the desired form. I also carefully read the textbook, but I didn't get any hint. Actually, I don't feel good in doing this question, because I don't have much background in solving specific ODEs.

Could anyone give me some help? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to take a stab at this.  Analogously to the situation with ODEs, suppose $P(z)$ is a polynomial with distinct roots $r_1, \dots, r_n$.  Then
$$e^{r_1 \bar{z}}, \dots, e^{r_n \bar{z}}$$
should each be solutions to the equation $P(\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}})h=0$.  Indeed, they would make up a fundamental solution set, and the general solution should be:
$$h(z,\bar{z}) = h_1(z)e^{r_1 \bar{z}} + \cdots+ h_n(z)e^{r_1 \bar{z}},$$
where $h_1, \dots, h_n$ are entire functions.

If we have roots of $P(z)$ with multiplicity, I suppose we must modify our fundamental solutions in the usual way by multiplying by powers of $\bar{z}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I'm not familiar with the theory of ODEs, I think you are right. But could you explain a little bit why $exp(r_{1}\bar{z})$, ..., $exp(r_{n}\bar{z})$ form a fundamental solution set? Put is another way, is it true that the solution set is a n-dimensional vector space with holomorphic function as scalars? Of course I'll also check some references in ODEs and find out an analogous proof.

Comment: Well it is true in the ODE situation, and I'm guessing it carries over to here, but I suppose there is something to prove.